# Fermat's Last Theorem for Gaussian Integers (excluding the integers or  same pure imaginaries)

Tags: number-theory

I am investigating solutions to Fermat's equation
$$x^n + y^n = z^n$$
with $x,y,z$ in the Gaussian integers, excluding integers and pure imaginaries.

I have found out that there are only trivial solutions for the $n=3$ and $n=4$ cases, e.g. [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/i32/i32.pdf).

I would be grateful if you let me know of the current status or if it is already a theorem.

Comment: Please don't make posts where "the title says it all". The title is like the writing on the spine of a book; the contents of the post should be sufficient by themsleves.

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to mathoverflow?

Comment: @Arturo, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ben, now I am feeling the same. But Motizens feel that questions posted here should at least have a 24 hour life or more before they   pass to the other elite society.

Comment: I have reposted this question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90972/fermats-last-theorem-for-gaussian-integers-excluding-mathbbz-or-i-mathbb

Comment: This question has been answered on the bigger sister site.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above in the comments, the question has been [answered on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90972/fermats-last-theorem-for-gaussian-integers-excluding-mathbbz-or-i-mathbb/91164#91164): it's still an open problem.

*(This answer is community wiki so that it won't generate any reputation.)*

Comment: Related [2013 MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466705/solutions-in-complex-number-field-instead-of-mathbbn-to-fermats-last-the).