# Solutions in complex number field, instead of $\mathbb{N}$, to Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

As far as I know, we are searching solutions in set of positive integers for $x^n + y^n = z^n$  for $n > 2$. There are many proofs are stated that Fermat is true and there is no solutions for this equations. Now my question is, can we have solutions in complex numbers field? If yes, how to find them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why going to the complex field? Why not  start with the real field? There are going to be lots of solutions there...

Comment: Sir, You are great! can you show me the real field solutions by proof please...

Comment: Well, for example with $\,z=\sqrt[3]9\;$ (real cubic root) , you have $\;1^3+2^3=z^3\;$...and you can do thesame with any natural power

Comment: @DonAntonio! even I have a solution in C: x = 3 + (square root 7)i, y = 4, z = -1 + (square root 7)i and n = 4. But. I am seriously looking for proof for producing such solutions.

Answer (score 4):

In the complex numbers, you can pick literally *any* $x$, $y$, and $n$ you want (with $x$ and $y$ complex).  Then compute $x^n + y^n$.  In the complex numbers this has $n$ different $n$th roots, unless it is zero, in which case it has only one $n$th root.  So pick any of these $n$ roots (or $0$ in the second case) for $z$, and you have a solution.

In the real numbers, the same method actually turns out to work.  As before, pick your favorite $x,y,n$ ($x,y$ real numbers now) and compute $x^n + y^n$.  If $n$ is odd, then every real number has a real $n$th root (for example every real number has a cube root) so we can pick this for $z$ and we're done.  If $n$ is even, we need the expression to be nonnegative in order to have a real $n$th root.  But $x^n$ and $y^n$ will both be $\ge 0$, so $x^n + y^n$ is nonnegative, so we can likewise pick $z$ to be the $n$th root and we run into no problems.  In fact in the even case there is a positive and a negative $n$th root, hence 2 options for $z$ given $x,y,$ and $n$.

Comment: @Gos! somewaht good. I need a proof for generating solutions in R as well as in C separately.

Comment: @prof.dr.math I've edited to include a solution for the real numbers.  Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: @Gos! You are very much correct. Can we find in complex hyper space

Comment: @prof.dr.math I do not know this "complex hyper space".  If you want to ask additional questions you should edit them into your question, and if you are adding too many additional questions (like, more than 2) it would probably be best to pose an entirely new question.

Comment: If you are wondering about solutions to $x^n + y^n = z^n$ in a general set (e.g. "what is a condition on a field $F$ such that it has solutions to this equation?) then it would be better to pose this one general question than to pose repeated examples.

Comment: ! There is no specific condition on F at this time

Answer (score 2):

I think original question should be "are there FLT solutions for gaussian integers"?

These are complex numbers where both part (real and imaginary) are integers

In this field, "primes" for instance are different than integers

By searching on google about it, I learned this post, but there is no easy info about FLT on gaussian integers, which is is strange since it appears to be an obvious question .

thanks

Miguel