# Complex version of the Fermat last problem

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

A complex integer is a complex number $x=m+ni$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

> Are there complex integers $x,y,z$ with $x^3+y^3=z^3$?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  What have you tried (expanding the equation out with complex numbers and seeing what the real and complex parts must satisfy, for example), and what sparked this interest?  Questions with context and background tend to attract better answers.

Comment: These are called Gaussian integers, they form a unique factorization domain. It could be helpful.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90972/fermats-last-theorem-for-gaussian-integers-excluding-mathbbz-or-i-mathb

Comment: See also this [MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119000/fermats-last-theorem-for-gaussian-integers-excluding-the-integers-or-same-pur).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lampakis 2007 provided a new proof there are no $xyz\ne 0$ solutions. It runs to [several pages](http://emis.ams.org/journals/INTEGERS/papers/i32/i32.pdf). Lampakis notes Feuter 1913 provided the original proof, but I couldn't find an online link to his reference, R. Feuter, Sitzungsber. Akad. Wiss. Heidelberg (Math.), 4, A, 1913 No. 25.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your  answer.